# how to display images whose names are stored in database

Tags: mysql, database

I had created a table in mysql database. I am using php  One column was for images, but it only stored images name. I wanted to print the whole table so did the coding but got got only the name of the images in the table.

Please explain how can I display images on the webpage that are stored in my PC. I don't want to save images in the database.

I used this code to print the table :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("test", $con);


$query="SELECT * FROM images LIMIT 0,5";
$result = @mysql_query($query);
echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>S.No.</th>
<th>Image</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['image_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Hope you got some answer....

Comment: Please show the code you have.

Comment: You did not even specify what language you are working in. Please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask before asking questions.

Comment: When you say you have the names of the images I assume you mean the filenames with directory path?  You are using those to create image tags in the HTML and the files are on the same computer that's hosting the page?

Comment: yes sir I mean filenames

Answer (score 0):

All your code is doing is sending the filename to the screen as a string.  You need to the use image tags.

You may find this page useful, http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/images/_IMG.html

Comment: you have given the link for html codes, but I am using php - 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['image_id'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['filename'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

What code should I add to the above code to get the images

Comment: See that <td> and </td>, that's HTML.  You're using PHP server side to generate HTML that will be displayed on the users PC.  The PHP needs to pull the links to the images from the database and then dynamically generate the HTML.  If you display the link to the image without surrounding it in an image tag it will treat it as text and will not display the image.